# Sql server CASE and IN where clause

Tags: sql-server, case, where-clause, where-in

Can Somebody help me with following sql query.

When you want to filter by Phase I, It should return results with Phase I or Phase I/II but not Phase II or Phase III.

Similarly for Phase II, it should return results with Phase I/II, Phase II or Phase II/III

```
select Phase from Phases where Phase in (case 

when @phase='Phase I' then '''Phase I'',''Phase I/II'''
when @phase='Phase II' then '''Phase I/II'',''Phase II'',''Phase II/III'''
end)
```

I do not want to use dynamic query to solve the issue.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Post some date and the desired return for you query.

Comment: When you want to filter by Phase I, It should look for Phase I or Phase I/II but not Phase II or Phase III.   Similarly for Phase II, it should return results with Phase I/II, Phase II or Phase II/III

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boolean logic can solve this:

```
select Phase 
  from Phases 
 where (@phase = 'Phase I'  and Phase in ('Phase I', 'Phase I/II'))
    or (@phase = 'Phase II' and Phase in ('Phase I/II', 'Phase II', 'Phase II/III'))
```